# volver al menu no funciona -lenguaje C

Tags: c, condiciones, subconsultas, switch, menu

estoy haciendo un menú de opciones el cual está contenido en una función menu(); pero cuando verifico si alguien quiere volver al menú (volver a ejecutar la función menu) el programa finaliza, no hay errores pero simplemente finaliza el programa

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

system("COLOR 02");
//bienvenida();
menu();
return 0;
}
int menu(){
   int opcion;
   char vAM;
   //MENU
   printf("\n\t\t\t\t**********Bienvenido a Cinematic***********\n\n\nBienvenido al menú de 
   opciones\n\n1) COMPRAR BOLETOS\n2) CONSULTAR BOLETOS COMPRADOS\n3) VER CARTELERA \n");
   printf("\n¿Introduzca el número de la acción que desea hacer? ");
   scanf("%d", &opcion);
   printf("\n");

   if(opcion == 1)
   {

       comprarBoleto();

       return 1;
   }
   if(opcion == 2)
   {
       consultarUsuario();
   }
   if(opcion == 3)
   {
     
       consultarCartelera();
       printf("\n¿Desea volver al menu? (s/n)");
       scanf("%c", sn);
       if(sn=='s'){
           menu();
       }

   }
}
```

Comment: definitivamente, hacer una llamada recursiva (llamar a menu dentro de menu) no es una buena idea aquí

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("%c", sn);
```

Debería ser

```
scanf("%c", &sn);
//          ^ importante
```

Por otro lado, quizás deberías considerar la posibilidad de usar un bucle en vez de llamadas recursivas a la función:

```
char sn='s';
do
{
   printf("\n\t\t\t\t**********Bienvenido a Cinematic***********\n\n\nBienvenido al menú de 
   opciones\n\n1) COMPRAR BOLETOS\n2) CONSULTAR BOLETOS COMPRADOS\n3) VER CARTELERA \n");
   printf("\n¿Introduzca el número de la acción que desea hacer? ");
   scanf("%d", &opcion);
   printf("\n");

   if(opcion == 1)
   {
       // ...
   }
   if(opcion == 2)
   {
       consultarUsuario();
   }
   if(opcion == 3)
   {
       consultarCartelera();
       printf("\n¿Desea volver al menu? (s/n)");
       scanf("%c", &sn);
   }
} while (sn == 's');
```

Answer (score 0):

Has probado a utilizar, ya que las opciones son limitadas y están definidas, usar "switch" y "cases"?

Soy muy, muy nuevo en ésto, pero si el programa finaliza sin marcar errores, seguramente la sinstaxis esté bien y sea un problema de control de flujo.

Al ser una condición anidada, aunque no sea dentro de un ciclo, puede que el comando "goto" te pueda servir también.

Por último:

if(opcion == 3)
{

```
   consultarCartelera();
   printf("\n¿Desea volver al menu? (s/n)");
   scanf("%c", sn);
   if(sn=='s'){
       menu();
   }
```

(A éste bloque podría añadirle algo como...

char primeracadena= "s";
char segundacadena= "n";

```
   if(sn == primeracadena) bla, bla, bla
```